# Ubuntu 20.04 get stuck

Tags: 20.04

I  have  currently installted  Ubuntu 20.04  and  when ever  I  try to  open  an internet browser like crome/firefox  it  hopelessly  get stuck and  later when i apply a  hard  reboot ,It  start working  fine  .Please  advise  if there is any resolution  for the  same

Comment: How much RAM do you have?

Comment: It is   2 gb Ram ***********

Comment: This is the reason. Have at least 4GB of it and it will get better. Otherwise try LUbuntu or XUbuntu

Comment: Thanks  Sir/Ma'am for the  help ,I  will get  it  upgraded